# Draw a turtle path without Turtle module

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to code a program that draws the path of a 'turtle' when given a string. I can't use the turtle module. We suppose the turtle starts at (0,0) and points toward *y*.

Here are the 4 possible caracters:

S: Go forward 1 in the current direction;
R: Turns right 90 degrees;
L: Turns left 90 degrees;
T: Disables displacement tracking if it is currently active, otherwise enables it.

For example, a path could be: SSSRSSLSTSST

I see two ways to approch this problem. Either the turtle is always moving straight in a plane that rotates. Either the particle can 'recognize' where it is actually pointing, and then move left and right.

In both situations, I'm stuck.

Here is the 'code' I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


pathUser=input('Write a path')           #User enter a path
path=list(pathUser)                      #Convert string to a matrix

x=0
y=0

for p in path:                           #Check  the letters one-by-one

    if p == "S":
        y=y+1                            #Moves straight
        plt.plot(x,y,'k^')       
  
    elif p == "R":
        
    elif p == "L":
        
    elif p == "T":   
            
plt.show()
```

Is it a good start? What I can do it rotates the point, but not the axis.
Can someone could help me to figure out what to put in R and L parts?
Thank you in advance for your time and your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: S will go along the y axis only if the turtle is facing North, the same way as in the start. But after turning, it will face West or East. You can solve the problem for instance by remembering the [dx,dy] direction vector of the turtle heading. Then S will just add the vector to [x,y]. Turning will change the vector to [-dy,dx] or [dy,-dx] - depending on whether you turn 'L'eft or 'R'ight. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For turtle graphics, we need to store and update both direction and positions.
Here a simple way:

1. initialize position and direction
2. if S: change position acc. to the direction
3. if R: change direction by -90 degrees
   if L: change direction by +90 degrees

Here's sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


direction = 90
track     = True
move_dir  = {  0: [ 1,  0],
              90: [ 0,  1],
             180: [-1,  0],
             270: [ 0, -1]}

x, y = [0, 0]
prev_x, prev_y = x, y
path = input('write a path: \n>>>')


for p in path:
    if p == 'S':
        prev_x, prev_y = x, y
        x += move_dir[direction][0]
        y += move_dir[direction][1]
        if track:
            plt.plot([prev_x, x], [prev_y, y], color='red', marker='.', markersize=10)
    
    elif p == 'L':
        direction = (direction + 90) % 360

    elif p == 'R':
        if direction == 0:
            direction = 270
        else:
            direction = direction - 90
    
    else:
        track = not track


plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Sample test case:

```
write a path:
>>>SSSRSSLSTSSTS
```

outputs:

[image]